will key expire during transaction in redis?
I run commands like this:
del dict
echo "log: set foo, expire 1"
hset dict key bar
expire dict 1

multi
hset dict key nowatchvalue
debug sleep 1
hget dict key
exec

the results shows:
(integer) 1
"log: set foo, expire 1"
(integer) 1
(integer) 1
OK
QUEUED
QUEUED
QUEUED
1) (integer) 0     // result from "hset dict key nowatchvalue"
2) OK              // result from "debug sleep 1"
3) "nowatchvalue"  // result from "hget dict key"
(1.00s)

Since I didn't use watch, why the key dict didn't disappear after debug command?

A key can expire between MULTI and EXEC, but not during EXEC.
Here is an example:
127.0.0.1:6379> SET x 1
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> EXPIRE x 10
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> INCR x
QUEUED

wait >10 seconds
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> EXEC
1) (integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> GET x
"1"

You can see that x was expired before EXEC was called.
Redis cannot delay expirations just because one client has a dangling MULTI.
However, during EXEC - the time 'freezes' between the first command and the last command execution, and keys cannot expire:
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> TIME
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> DEBUG SLEEP 1
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> TIME                                                                    
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> DEBUG SLEEP 1
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> TIME                                                                    
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> EXEC
1) 1) "1715176972"
   2) "436158"
2) OK
3) 1) "1715176972"
   2) "436158"
4) OK
5) 1) "1715176972"
   2) "436158"
(2.00s)


I ran your code, the time will change between multi and exec; my redis version was 6.0.16

MULTI is the start of the transaction's definition. The time of calling MULTI has no meaning. EXEC executes the transaction. The code demonstrates that the time does not change during the transaction's execution.
